# "it got me back to using" or "it got me back into using"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice

Which sentence makes sense?

> 1. Quarantine got me back to using my treadmill again.
> 2. Quarantine got me back into using my treadmill again.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences make sense, but mean different things.  Intended meaning is what needs to be considered.

To say "back to using" means that an action that once was happening is happening again.

The preposition "into" has many meanings.  The one that applies in your example seems to be:

> **into:**  enthusiastic about or interested in

With this definition, "back into using" suggests how the speaker feels about "using" something.